# Is it possible to read the next line of a file only if a particular IF statement is valid?

Tags: batch-file, line, counter, increment

I wondered, is it possible to skip reading a line in a FOR /F loop if a certain IF statement is valid in it?
For example:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%j in (exclusions.txt) do ( 
IF %SomethingIDeclaredBefore%==%%j (jump to the next line of the text file) else (echo not equal)
```

I suppose it's impossible to increment `%%j.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
for /l %%C in (1,1,254) do (
 findstr /b /e "172.24.104.%%C" exclusions.txt >nul
 if errorlevel 1 (echo shutdown) else (echo skip)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.
Just do an if statement that checks `if not %SomethingIDeclaredBefore%==%%j`.  This way only the lines that do not match the statement will be processed in the loop, essentially skipping the line.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%j in (exclusions.txt) do ( 
    IF NOT %SomethingIDeclaredBefore%==%%j (echo not equal)
)
```

### Update

If I understand your scenario from your comment, this should do what you want.  To check for exclusions for each address, the full exclusions loop must be within the address loop.

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%C IN (1,1,254) DO (
    SET "Found=false"
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%J IN (exclusions.txt) DO (
        IF "172.24.104.%%C"=="%%J" SET "Found=true"
    )
    IF "!Found!"=="true" ( ECHO Skip ) ELSE ( ECHO Shutdown )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I should have made the meaning of my question more clear, so let me introduce the background: I have to compare two ip addresses, in 2 enmeshed FOR loops: Note: exclusions.txt is full of restricted ip addresses 

    `FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%j in (exclusions.txt) do ( FOR /L     %%C in (1,1,254) do ( echo 172.24.104.%%C echo %%j IF NOT     172.24.104.%%C==%%j (echo Shutdown) PAUSE` If two addresses match, then do nothing and skip the `%%j` line in exclusion.txt to next, otherwise, shutdown the computer with this `%%j` ip address. Shutdown should operate on `%%j`.